# Yacc rules for ambiguous grammar

Tags: bison, yacc

I am trying to write a yacc grammer to recognize the following pattern:

```
AAAA  -> Multiple As
BBBB  -> Multiple Bs
AAAABB -> 2 As followed by (AABB)
AAABBBBB  -> (AAABBB) followed by 2Bs
```

In general, I would like to group equal blocks of contiguous As and Bs together, in precedence over runs of just As or Bs. A straightforward grammar shows a bunch of conflicts.

I need a way to give precedence to this production.

```
T -> | AB | ATB
```

over

```
U -> | AU
```

(where T and U are yacc productions, A and B are tokens)

How is this done?

Answer (score 2):

In general, yacc cannot deal with ambiguous grammars.  If you give it an ambiguous grammar (or any non-LALR(1) grammar), it will parse a subset of the language of that grammar, which may or may not be what you want.

With bison, you can use `%glr-parser` to create a glr parser that can parse an ambiguous grammar.  However, you need to add `%dprec` and `%merge` directives to the appropriate spots in the grammar to resolve ambiguities, or you'll end up with a runtime error.

However, the language you've described isn't particularly ambiguous.  In fact, its fairly trivially LALR(1), so can be easily handled by yacc:

```
%token A B
%%
input: multiA | multiB | twoA | twoB ;
multiA: A | A A | A A A | A A A moreAs ;
moreAs: A | moreAs A ;
multiB: B | multiB B ;
twoA: A A A A B B ;
twoB: A A A B B B B B ;
```

Comment: This would not accept all strings of the form (A^n B ^n). Sorry if I was not clear initially.

Comment: @Kumar: Such strings are not in the pattern you described.  Perhaps if you give the grammar you are trying to use, we can give some advice on how to deal with the ambiguity

Comment: This is what I want to do. In a long stream of As and Bs, I would like to group A^n B^n in priority over grouping contiguous As or Bs: The two productions for T and U above indicate this. So, if I have the stream AAAABBAAAABBBABBBAB, I want to parse this as AA (AABB) A (AAABBB) A BBB (AB), rather than as blocks of of As and Bs. Hope I am clear now.